# Передача enum class в конструктор

Tags: c++, c++11, enum

```
enum class EmployeeType {Employee, Manager, Sales, Unknown};

class Employee
{
public:
    Employee() = delete;
    Employee(const Employee&) = delete;
    Employee& operator=(const Employee&) = delete;
    Employee& operator=(Employee&&) = delete;

    Employee(Employee&&) = default;

    explicit Employee(EmployeeType type);
}
```

Когда пишу в main():

```
Employee e1(EmployeeType::Manager);
```

или

```
Employee e2(Employee(EmployeeType::Manager));
```

то работает.
Хочу запретить такую конструкцию, которую допускает компилятор:

```
Employee e3({});
Employee e4(EmployeeType{});
Employee e5(EmployeeType(123));
```

Как это сделать? В этом случае в конструктор приходит EmployeeType::Employee, то есть ноль.

Следующие вызывы будут считаться допустимыми.

```
Employee e6(EmployeeType::Employee);
Employee e7(EmployeeType::Manager);
Employee e8(EmployeeType::Sales);
Employee e9(EmployeeType::Unknown);
Employee e10(Employee(EmployeeType::Employee));
Employee e11(Employee(EmployeeType::Manager));
Employee e12(Employee(EmployeeType::Sales));
Employee e13(Employee(EmployeeType::Unknown));
```

Использую g++ 5.4.0 в Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Работаю в Qt Creator 4.1.0 c включенными 11-ыми плюсами в pro-файле:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45270810

Answer (score 1):

Можно предотвратить вызов `Employee e3({});`, объявив конструктор с `initializer_list`. Он всегда предпочтительнее, когда инициализатор — фигурные скобки.

```
Employee(std::initializer_list<int>) = delete;
```

Тип шаблона в действительности не имеет значения.

Однако нет возможности запретить вызывающему преобразовать какое-либо значение в `EmployeeType` и затем использовать его как аргумент конструктора.

<sub>Это перевод ответа [Pass enum class as a parameter of constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45270857).</sub>